# TAR command file extension path expansion

Tags: linux, bash, path, tar, file-extension

Okay, this should be easy but I tried braces and brackets to get this to work but it has been too long since I did UNIX shell scripting.

I want to do quick backups using TAR of just selected files in a few directories, only those with PHP, HTML, CSS, or BMP extensions. Who has the fix?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~ ; x="public_html/gpp"

targpp="tar -cvf gppbasic.`date +%Y%m%d.%k%M`.tar $x/*.[php|html|css|bmp]"

$targpp  ;  ls -l gppbasic*.tar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try curly bracket

```
tar -cvf gppbasic.$(date +%Y%m%d.%k%M).tar $x/*.{php,html,css,bmp}
```

Comment: Surprisingly that worked even though I had tried exactly that (see "braces" mentioned in question) and it had failed. The only difference seems to be that you changed the way the date/time code was generated but I don't know why that would affect it.

Comment: I don't think `backtick` and `$()` made any difference, I tried assigning the command to `targpp`, then ran `$targpp`, neither way worked. `*.{php,html,css,bmp}` is treated as literal string instead of being expanded. But if I ran the `tar` command directly, both way worked.